# to escape or not to escape: well formed XHTML with diacritics

Tags: xhtml, unicode

Say that you have a XHTML document in English but it has accented characters (e.g. `meta name="author" content="José"`). Let's say you have no control over the HTTP headers.

1. Should the characters be replaced for their corresponding named entities (e.g. `&aacute;`, etc)?
2. Should the xml:lang attribute be set to English?

I know I can check the W3C recommendation but I am asking more from a practical point of view.

Comment: What encoding is the document using? What language is the content in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should the characters be replaced for their corresponding named entities (e.g. `&aacute;`, etc)?

Since you can't control the HTTP headers (and thus the declared character encoding) you should encode everything using ASCII (since it is a safe subset of just about everything).

This will require that you use entities for anything that isn't in ASCII. Named ones are preferred (as they are easier for people editing the HTML to handle) but not required.

> Should the doc type and the xml:lang attribute be set to English?

The `EN` in the Doctype is a reference to the language that the comments **in the DTD** are written in. The HTML 3.x / 4.x and XHTML 1.x Doctypes must always use `EN`.

The `lang` attribute (and *additionally* the `xml:lang` attribute) should specify the language that the content is written in. If that is English, then it should be English.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I kind of missed the point, so here's the answer, and following up is the rant on encodings.

`xml:lang="en"` doesn't forbid you from using any character you want, it's only metadata for use by browser, search engines, accessibility software, etc. If you page *is* in English, then go ahead, write it.

As of diacritics, HTML supports both directly writing the character or writing the entity, both in attributes and in text nodes (and possibly in node names too, but I'm not sure; anyways, that's not going to happen with HTML). However, it's easier in my opinion to use UTF-8 everywhere than to escape entities; and there are like 4 ways to set the encoding of a page, so it would be hard to believe that, in a practical case, you can't do it.

---

From a practical point of view, being a French speaker with diacritics in my first name, I find it is a **MAJOR** annoyance (and markdown won't let me stress **MAJOR** enough) when websites don't support accentuated letters. Even if you set `xml:lang` to English, it's not going to solve this problem.

I recommend that you use UTF-8 because it is backwards-compatible with ASCII and it can encode every UCS character. If you have no control over the HTTP headers, you still have two options: the XML declaration, and the `meta` tag.

If I recall correctly, if you get an XML document, the `encoding` "attribute" in the `<?xml?>` tag has precedence. This is your first solution, but it's probably not supported by legacy browsers.

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Your other option, and by far better supported, is to use the `meta` tag to tell the browser about the encoding. In HTML4-, you can use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

In HTML5+, you can use this simpler form:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Since you use XHTML, you'll want to self-close these (and use the appropriate `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type in the `Content-Type` `<meta>` tag).

Comment: Don't use the XML declaration. It triggers quirks mode in IE6 and shouldn't be used for character encoding in text/html documents (and if you use application/xhtml+xml then IE8 and lower won't be rendering the page at all)

Comment: The question also states that he has no control over the HTTP headers, and real HTTP headers take priority over any character encoding information in `<meta>` data, so it is possible that this can be overriden.

Comment: Whether it's "easier...to use UTF-8 everywhere than to escape entities" depends heavily on what language the document is in.  English is only going to have a handful of non-ASCII characters, so you might as well write the escapes.

Comment: @dan04 You can also see it the other way: since English is only going to have a handful of non-ASCII characters, it's easy to forget to escape them. If you use UTF-8, you simply don't need to care about it.